Can I do a difference-in-difference analysis if my outcome variable is nominal?
When the outcome variable is nominal and has more than two categories that are not in a specific order, can I still perform a difference-in-difference analysis?
I am interested coordination among spouse when negative economic shock strikes in. I measure coordination as a discrete variable that takes value 1 if both husband and wife within a household are working, 2 if husband is working and his wife is not working, 3 if wife is working and her husband is not working, 4 if neither is working.
The economic shock is measured as an interaction of treatment and time dummy. Treatment dummy takes value 1 if the household is from affected district and 0 otherwise. Time dummy takes value 1 for post-shock time period and 0 for pre-shock time period.

Yes, you sort of can (but I would not really call it DiD). Look at the counts of your nominal variable (1-4) before, and after the "treatment". Arrange it in a 4x2 table, and run a test of association (Fisher-eaxct, $\chi^2$) to see if the proportions are similar, or not. Now, if the trest is significant, all it will tell you is that the proportions have changed, but how they have changed, which have changed the most, etc. For this, you can run 4 (1 for each level of your nominal variable) 2x2 contingency tables, to see which category changed significantly. Use a multiple comparison correction (MCC; e.g. Bonferroni or Sidak).
But in your case, you can turn your categorical variable into a numerical, ratio scale one. From the change in your outcome variable, compute the "# of working partners" variable. This will go from -2 to 2; and on it, you can run t-tests, etc.
One small issue with this is that, if 1 spouse started working while the other stopped, this will be counted as 0, i.e. "no change". This may, or not be an issue for your study (depends on what the purpose is).
One way to remedy this, is to look at each spouse separately; now you numeric variable goes from -1 to 1, and it does not confuse one spouse starting working while the other stopped with "no change".
PS: your categorical variable may be missing some scenarios, wrt spouses having more than 1 job; they may be adding a 2nd job, or losing one of their 2 jobs (or both), etc. As worded, you are not taking this into account (which may, or not, matter for the study).

It will be an issue if I cannot capture when one spouse started working while the other stopped. Given this scenario, I am thinking to consider a binary outcome variable: it takes value 1 if wife is in labor force, provided that the husband is in labor force and 0 if wife is not in labor force, conditional on that the husband is in labor force. What do you think of this?

Also, I was reading  Ai and Norton (2003) (link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/scienc...65176503000326 ) which says that in nonlinear models, the coefficient I obtain as an interaction term is very different from the interaction effect. But I could not understand the alternative provided in it

If you go purely binary, you will lose a lot of information. That really does not sound like the right approach.  If you want to catch when one spouse started work, while the other stopped, analyze husband/wife separately. Btw, the first approach (contingency tables) also catches that situation w/o problem; one count goes up by 1, another goes down by 1; so there is a difference). Btw, the link does not work...

Here's the correct link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165176503000326 (Sorry that the previous link did not work). The full reference to the paper is: Ai & Norton. 2003. Interaction terms in logit and probit models. Economics Letters 80(1):123−129.

Thank you for your reply. I agree that if I use binary variable, that will result in lots of lost information. But if I do separate regression for husband and wife, how can I make sure that the difference in their coefficients will capture the variation in outcome for a couple? Also, my objective is to see whether the economic shock increases/decreases women's labor force participation/non-participation compared to men in a household. But because marital status capture social norms, I thought to focus on couple. Do you think there is other way to measure the outcome variable?

If one spouse starts working while the other stops, there is no variation in outcome for the couple (single wage earner couple). On the other hand, looking separately at husbands vs. wives, will tell if there you if there is a significant difference in workforce participation between between before and after, and between the 2, which seems to be exactly what you want. E.g. ~ stable for husbands and increase for wives, or various combinations, including no significant change for either (between before and after)

Thank you for the insightful suggestions! So, I'll do separate regressions for husbands and wives and check for the significance of difference in estimated coefficients.
